# Parent container gaining mystery height

Tags: css

I have a div with two unordered lists within it.

Using Firebug the height of each unordered list (as shown in the layout tab) is 35px and 38px respectively, yet the height of the parent div is 41px.

What would cause this?

Here is a stripped example of the code as it is on an internal development server I can't link to it!:

```
<div class="actions">
    <ul class="first-ul"></ul>
    <ul class="second-ul"></ul>
</div>

    header.header .actions ul {
        display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    header.header .actions ul.first-ul {
        float: left;
    }
```

Comment: Use chrome to "Inspect Element" and see whereabouts the additional height is, then go from there

Comment: Using `display: inline;` and `float: left;` is redundant; use either of the two methods…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had similar problems - in my case the height was caused by whitespace characters between the `ul` and `li` elements, which was really hard to figure out, even with a DOM inspector. Changing from this

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

to this:

```
<ul><li></li><li></li></ul>
```

fixed it for me. Not sure if this is the same issue, but worth trying.

Comment: Bang on. I had this problem with a CSS rule before, how the hell do they sneak in there?!